# Search in the list

Tags: python

```
class CommandManager:
        def __init__(self):
            self.commands = []

        def add_command(self, command: Command):
            if command is None:
                return None

            for target in self.commands:
                if target.name is command.name:
                    return None

            print(command.name, command.description, command.usage, command.min_arguments)  # debug

            self.commands.append(command)
            return command

        def get_command(self, name):
            if name is None:
                return None    
            for target in self.commands:
                if name is target.name:
                    return target    
            return None
```

What's wrong with this code? Adding to the array and looking for it in the `add_command` method works fine, but in`get_command` it does not find it. No value is `None`.

Comment: Don't compare strings with `is`.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` tests for identity, not equality. That means Python simply compares the memory address a object resides in.

you should use == operator to test equality of a string like:

```
if name == target.name:
```

Answer (score 0):

`is` operator tests if two variables point to the same object. Use `==` instead.

```
if name == target.name:
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, but I have marked the earlier answer D: